# Hidden frame for Browser History support

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, browser-history

Can anyone tell me the purpose of the following code and when/where you would use it. Is it some way to manipulate the browser history in IE?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"> 
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1"> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        function processUrl()
        {
            var pos = url.indexOf("?");
            url = pos != -1 ? url.substr(pos + 1) : "";
            if (!parent._ie_firstload) {
                parent.BrowserHistory.setBrowserURL(url);
                try {
                    parent.BrowserHistory.browserURLChange(url);
                } catch(e) { }
            } else {
                parent._ie_firstload = false;
            }
        }

        var url = document.location.href;
        processUrl();
        document.write(url);
    </script>
    Hidden frame for Browser History support.
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a buggy `historyFrame.html` from Adobe Flex with a cross-site scripting bug.

- A brief summary: http://secunia.com/advisories/30746/
- A fix for it: http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/06/18/flex-3-historymanager-exploit/

The HTML file apparently allows you to control the history of the browser to some degree via Flex.